# generate conditional column in pandas

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I have:

```
pd.DataFrame({'price':['45p','£1.35']})
```

I want to convert these to numeric, and get:

```
pd.DataFrame({'price':['45p','£1.35'],'numeric':[0.45,1.35]})
```

I tried:

```
df['numeric']=np.where(df.price.str.contains('p') is True,
                  pd.to_numeric(df.price.str.replace('p',''))/100,
                 pd.to_numeric(df.price.str.replace('£','')))
```

and got the following error: `ValueError: Unable to parse string "£1.35" at position 7`

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one step at a time:

```
# where values in pennies
is_pennies = df['price'].str.contains('p')

# remove the currency characters and convert to numerics
df['price'] = df.price.str.replace('p|£', '').astype(float)

# update the values in pennies
df.loc[is_pennies, 'price'] /= 100
```

Output:

```
   price
0   0.45
1   1.35
```